# Vim - open new tab in buffer

Tags: vim

I jsut switched from sublime text to vim and I'm trying to replicate sublime's tab view.

I usually have a vertical split opened with `:vsp` and each split I'd like to open new tabs. To do this I type in `bufdo tab split` but it opens a new tab over my split and not within the split.

How can I open the tab within the split?

Many thanks

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. A tab can be split, but you cannot have tabs in a split.

Comment: In vim, tabs are quite different from what other editors' tabs. In vim, a tab is a container of windows (and each window is a view of a particular location of a text buffer/file). Is there something you're trying to achieve? Maybe we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Are you just trying to view a new buffer inside a split window you already have? For that there are various buffer-switching commands. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Buffers has a nice overview of how buffers, tabs, and windows all fit together. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages has more on tabs, as well as other tips in the same category.

Answer (score 48):

To Open a tab, editing the current file's name you can use `%`, which acts as a macro for the current file:

```
:tabe %
```

To Open a new tab & show the current file's directory:

`:Te` or `:tabe %:h`

To move between opened tabs:

```
gt # Go to next tab
gT # Go to previous tab
```

Comment: To open multiple files, each with its own tab, use the `-p` option: `vim -p file1.txt file2.c file3.py`

Answer (score 11):

In Vim, each edited file corresponds to a *buffer*. These are displayed in *windows*. Multiple windows can be *split*. Multiple such an arrangements of window(s) can be switched to in *tab pages* (this is a more recent addition).

In this hierarchy, the tab pages are always "above" the windows, so there can only be one single tabline that structures the tab pages. (And it's always between the menu / window title and the windows.)

In Vim, working with window splits is preferred over tab pages. It's recommended to use the latter only to separate different workspaces / projects, etc. Vim is very powerful (and with a long heritage), so you cannot directly take over concepts seen in other editors.